What was Harry implying when he said "it" was simple?
After successfully carrying out a 5 million dollar
heist with her crew, Veronica returned to her hideout
alone. There, she encountered Harry Rawlings, her
husband who everyone thought had died in a van
explosion while stealing $2,000,000 from crime
boss Jamal Manning, but had actually faked his own death. Then, he started the conversation:

Harry: Yeah. It was meant to be simple. Why couldn't you just
sell the book to Jamal and leave it at that, Ronnie?

What was Harry implying when he said "it" was simple?

I’m voting to close this question because it's about basic English understanding of a sentence/word

"It" refers to the initial plan that he and Veronica decided. So basically in this conversation with Veronica, he(Harry Rawlings) is expressing his disappointment.
By saying "Why couldn't you just sell the book to Jamal and leave it at that, Ronnie?" he's trying to say that Veronica could have avoided the complications and dangers that arise from the heist by simply sticking to the original plan of dealing with Jamal directly.
